# Issue passing data from activity to service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

'Below are my two classes which I'm trying to pass data from my activity to my service. I've passed to other Activities no problem but I when look for my extras in my IntentService it always comes back null. Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private Button mbutton;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.d("TestActivity", "onClick: starting srvice");
             Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this/*getApplicationContext()*/, MyService.class);
             /*TestActivity.this.getApplicationContext().*/
             intent.putExtra(MyService.PARAM_IN_NAME, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText());
             intent.putExtra(MyService.PARAM_IN_JOB, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText());
             intent.putExtra(MyService.PARAM_IN_BDAY, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText());
             startService(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is my Service class which I'm trying to extract my data from activity.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

public static final String PARAM_IN_NAME = "name";
public static final String PARAM_IN_JOB = "job";
public static final String PARAM_IN_BDAY = "bday";

private String mJob;
private String mBday;
private String mName;

// --------------CONSTRUCTORS--------------
public MyService() {
    super("MyServiceThread");
}

public MyService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

// -------------OVERRIDE-------------
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mName = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_NAME);
    mJob = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_JOB);
    mBday = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_BDAY);

    String result = "Name = " + mBday + " | Job = " + mJob + " | Bday = " + mBday; 

    Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

This is also what I have for my Manifest file:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService" android:enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking fine.

Try after adding `toString()` when you get text from the `EditText` like this:

`intent.putExtra(MyService.PARAM_IN_NAME,` `((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());`

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem! =D

Answer (score 6):

Use bundle for sending the data to the service.

From the activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putCharSequence("extraData", data);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Receives in service.

`Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  data = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraData");`

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does look a like a good move forward. However after I made the changes I now crash at the line:

data = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraData");

It still seems like I can't pass anything to my service.

Answer (score 0):

I hand my data over like this to the receiving end

```
  Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String scan = bundle.getString("scan");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.username)).setText(scan);
```